# Access selective folders in S3 bucket visa AWS Transfer User

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 3 folders in a S3 bucket and `AWS Transfer User` which has access to one folder in that bucket which is setup via terraform :

```
resource "aws_transfer_user" "foo" {
  server_id = aws_transfer_server.foo.id
  user_name = "tftestuser"
  role      = aws_iam_role.foo.arn

  home_directory_type = "LOGICAL"
  home_directory_mappings {
    entry  = "/test.pdf"
    target = "/bucket3/test-path/folder1"
    //target = "/bucket3/test-path/folder2" --> Something like this accessing folder1 and folder2
  }
}
```

Now I want it to have access to 2nd folder as well. Is it possible to add another folder to the user or I'll have to create a new `aws transfer user` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining multiple `home_directory_mappings` because terraform accepts multiple items in certain cases like `ordered_cache_behavior` in `aws_cloudfront_distribution`

Comment: You mean in the same resource ?

Comment: Yes. Quite possible.